# Removing and adding element in jquery not working as expected

Tags: jquery

I'm adding a sticky menu. The way I'm doing it is removing one and showing the other when scroll. It looked fine at first but then I realize that it is swapping the elements but not the content inside of them. Pay attention to the titles, "This is my red menu".

```
<nav>
    <div class="nav-one">
        <p>THIS IS MY RED MENU</p>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-two">
        <p>THIS IS MY GREEN MENU</p>
    </div>
</nav>
```

```js
$('.nav-two').hide();

$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 1) {
            $('.nav-one').removeClass('nav-one').addClass('nav-two');
        } else {
            $('.nav-two').removeClass('nav-two').addClass('nav-one');
        }
    });
});
```

What am I doing wrong? If you think it can be done differently, please let me know. This is my [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/5mh90jgg/5/).

Comment: You're not removing and adding elements at all. You're just changing the classes on them. Why would that have any effect on their contents? (Other than, say, CSS visibility/display rules.)

Comment: Your question is incomplete. Post the full necessary HTML, CSS, and JavaScript **in** the question, not just linked. Ideally, do a [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button), as that provides a nice runnable example right here on-site.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder It is in JsFiddle. If you put too much code, stackoverflow complains about it https://jsfiddle.net/5mh90jgg/5/

Comment: **Again:** The code must be **in** the question, not just linked. If there's too much code, it's not a **minimal** complete verifiable example, and posting too much code in jsFiddle is no better than posting it here.

Comment: Why would the text change? All your code is doing is adding/removing a class

Comment: Yeah as said above, all you are doing is changing the class, which is applying the css of the second item to the first and vice versa, not removing the element. Perhaps changing the css to display none when the scroll bar goes down might be a better alternative. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/4tuzLd16/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your code is doing is switching around classes on the `nav-*` elements. It doesn't change the text, nor the visible element at all. From your description of what you want to have happen you should instead be hiding/showing the relevant `.nav-*` element based on the current `scrollTop` of the window, which you can achieve using `toggle()`, like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('.nav-one').toggle($(this).scrollTop() == 0);
    $('.nav-two').toggle($(this).scrollTop() >= 1);
});
```

```js
.nav-two {
    /* other styling rules here... */
    display: none;
}
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/5mh90jgg/6/)

Note that I moved the hiding of the `.nav-two` element to the CSS to avoid a FOUC.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing classes, not the divs, so the text remains

one option for not changing your JS:

add this 2 css

```
.nav-two p:before {
  content: "THIS IS MY GREEN MENU";
  }
  .nav-one p:before {
  content: "THIS IS MY RED MENU";
  }
```

and remove the texts of your HTML

Another option, changing only JS

```
$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 1) {
      $('.nav-one').hide();
      $('.nav-two').show();
    } else {
      $('.nav-two').hide();
      $('.nav-one').show();
    }
  });
});
```